# Prove that $\operatorname{Inn}(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) \cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group with trivial center. Prove that: $$\operatorname{Inn}(\operatorname{Aut}(G)) \cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)$$

Comment: The standard phrase is 'trivial center'; I've tweaked your question to use that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki How strange it sounds if you replace standard terms with close synonyms huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that the map from $a$ to $f_a(x)=axa^{-1}$ from Aut$(G)$ to Inn$(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ is an isomorphism

Comment: If that map be isomorphism we claim that $G \cong Inn(G)$ and it is obvious because $G$ has trivial center